# Why can't I win due to "missing multiplier"?

Tags: mahjong, riichi-mahjong, yaku

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why couldn't this hand win with ron?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8462/why-couldnt-this-hand-win-with-ron)

Occasionally, I try to Ron, but get prompted that I cannot due to a "missing multiplier". What does this mean, and how can I avoid it?

Example: The marked tile was just discarded, but I can't Ron.
[image: img]

Edit: A quick explanation why this question is on-topic on this site instead of at gaming.stackexchange.com.

The exact term "no multiplier" is certainly specific to this implementation, but I believe the question applies to the game in general. This message does not appear to be a "bug" or "error message" but a valid notification that my hand is missing something. Maybe (I'm guessing here) it should just read "Your hand does not have enough yaku yet!" instead.