# Why couldn't I declare Tsumo with this hand?

Tags: mahjong, riichi-mahjong

I recently played a game of Mahjong on the internet, and I had gotten this hand

[2 Characters]
[3 Characters]
[North Wind]
[North Wind]

[4 Characters] <- Drawn Tile

[Melded Pon of 2 Bamboo]
[Melded Chi of 3-5 Bamboo]
[Melded Kan of 1 Characters]

but it wouldn't let me declare Tsumo. 
I had a few possible reasons why I couldn't but I don't know the game that well. Can you not have a pair of Winds to complete your hand? Or is my hand invalid in some way?

Here is my discards, it might serve some purpose -

[Characters] 7
[Bamboo] 4, 3, 1
[Dragons] Red, Green, White
[Winds] East, West

Answer (score 3):

Riichi Mahjong has a one-*yaku* minimum before you can complete your hand.  While *tsumo* gives you a *yaku* if the hand is still closed, it won't give you anything if you've already opened your hand by calling melds.

For further details, you can read the related answer here: [Why couldn't this hand win with ron?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/8463/1926)

Your hand, as it stands, doesn't have any *yaku*.  If the North wind was active (i.e. if you were playing in the North seat) you could earn a *yaku* by calling or drawing a third North tile, but then you would be stuck with a pair wait on one of the 2/3 character tiles.  Beyond that, about the only way you could win with that hand (short of hoping for a winning tile on the last draw or a *kan* draw) would be to swap out the characters and replace them with a set of dragons or an active wind.

Comment: Thanks! I had read a bit of the other thread, and I thought it was a different case...but it seems the answer was the same to both questions. I apologize for making a technically duplicate question. I usually go for Toitoi or Riichi, since usually every time I call on melds I end up in Furiten or something like this I couldn't understand haha. I'm studying up on yaku hands now :> This really helped me a lot!